# Проблема с WebBrowser в Access (vba)

Tags: javascript, vba, webbrowser, ms-access, textarea

Добрый день всем!
Мне необходим на базе Access подготовить базу хранения и редактор правил на некотором DSL. Для функциональности редактора использую WebBrowser. При загрузке формы использую метод `WebBrowser.Navigate "<Path>/index.html"`.
Html-файл содержит один элемент textarea. "На него" навешен скрипт на javascript, использующий библиотеку codemirror.
Суть проблемы: при открытии файла index.html через браузер либо, что самое интересное (для меня), в элементе управления WebBrowser в Excel все работает прекрасно, а на форме Access, к сожалению, скрипты не отрабатывают.
Ниже - текст index.html:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>CodeMirror</title>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\user1\Desktop\CM1\lib\codemirror.css">
    <script src="C:\Users\user1\Desktop\CM1\lib\codemirror.js"></script>
    <script src="C:\Users\user1\Desktop\CM1\mode\xml\xml.js"></script>
    <script src="C:\Users\user1\Desktop\CM1\mode\javascript\javascript.js">
    </script>
    <script src="C:\Users\user1\Desktop\CM1\mode\css\css.js"></script>
    <script src="C:\Users\user1\Desktop\CM1\mode\clike\clike.js"></script>
    <script src="C:\Users\user1\Desktop\CM1\mode\php/php.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
    <textarea id="PHPcode" cols="70" rows="20">function</textarea>
    </div>
    <script>
    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("PHPcode"), {
    lineNumbers: true, // Нумеровать каждую строчку.
    matchBrackets: true,
    mode: "application/x-httpd-php",
    indentUnit: 4, // Длина отступа в пробелах.
    indentWithTabs: true,
    enterMode: "keep",
    tabMode: "shift"
    });
    </script>
    <style>
    .CodeMirror {
    border: 1px solid cornflowerblue;
    }
    </style>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Очень прошу помочь, как сделать так, чтоб в WebBrowser отрабатывала логика из index.html

Comment: Вопрос закрыт. Спасибо, если Вы над ним подумали =)

Comment: Вы бы написали ответ, если сами решили - для других.

Comment: Ответа, по сути, нет. Провел пересборку файлов (моды Codemirror и сам исходник CodeMirror) и чудо свершилось. К соожалению (или счастью) проблема была в невнимательности.